# WPF DataGrid with continuous selection from the bottom up

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I make a DataGrid that only supports selection in a continuous range from the bottom and up? The user clicks one item and only this and items below it should become selected. I have a ViewModel with a IsSelected-property that I bind to the RowStyle like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

However I try this I get odd and strange behaviours that seem to conflict with how selection is handled by WPF in DataGrids internally. I can't seem to get this work like I want. Any suggestions?

The way I do the selection logic now is that I have a "selection manager" that kicks in when the bound IsSelected-property is updated by WPF and then selects more than one item, specifically all items below and including. But when for instance the user clicks an allready selected item I don't get any events at all (sometimes), perhaps because WPF thinks this is not needed since the property is allready selected. And there is more problems. Trying to think how I can circumnavigate all this internal logic without messing it up to much. I still want the normal selection look on the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your viewmodels are structured, but I will do it this way:

Create a SelectedItems property, as well as an UpdateSelectionCommand in your viewmodel. The GridView.SelectemItems is bound to the VM.SelectedItems

```
    private IList<SelectedItemViewModel> _SelectedItems;

    public IList<SelectedItemViewModel> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (_SelectedItems == null)
            {
                //populate selected items; 
            }
            return _SelectedItems;
        }
        private set
        {
            //set _selected items to null here. 
            //FirePropertyChanged(): forces repopulation of _SelectedItems based on the new selection
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateSelectionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(_ => SelectedItems = null, true));
        }
    }
```

The **UpdateSelectionCommand** is triggered by left mouse click (MouseUp event) - this should solve the issue where an item is already selected and re-selecting it does not trigger change.

Comment: I'm using DataGrid and not GridView and DataGrid.SelectedItems is readonly.

Comment: Thanks anyway, you pushed me in the right direction. The solution was to handle the click-event manually (and overriding the internal logic).